# Combinatorics question: number of functions

Tags: combinatorics

Let $f: \{1,2,3,4,5,6\} \to \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$

find number of possible $f$ given
$|(f^{-1})\{1\}|>3$

I tried to apply the inclusion-exclusion principle, as such:
Let $A_i, 3<i<7$, be the number of functions in which $|f^{-1} \{1\} |=i$.

$A_4= \binom{6}{2} 6^2=540$

$A_5=6 \cdot 6=36$

$A_6=1$

$A_4∩A_5=A_5=36$

$A_4∩A_6=A_6=1$

$A_5∩A_6=A_6=1$

$A_4∩A_5∩A_6=A_6=1$

$\downarrow$

$S=A_4+A_5+A_6-A_4∩A_5-A_4∩A_6-A_5∩A_6+A_4∩A_5∩A_6=$

$540+36+1-36-1-1+1=$

$577-38+1=540$

However, given that my answer was equal to $A_4$ I think that I am completely mistaken, and something went wrong, and so I ask for guidance.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than downvotes or votes to close if you [edit] the question to tell us what you tried and where you are stuck. This is not a "do it for me" site.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches, both based on conditioning on $k=|f^{-1}(1)|$.  There are then $\binom{6}{k}$ choices for which $k$ elements map to $1$ and $(6-1)^{6-k}$ functions from the remaining $6-k$ elements to $\{2,\dots,6\}$.

Counting directly yields
$$\sum_{k=4}^6 \binom{6}{k} (6-1)^{6-k} = 406.$$

Counting via the complement yields
$$6^6 - \sum_{k=0}^3 \binom{6}{k} (6-1)^{6-k} = 406.$$